# Реализация ссылок на объекты многих классов в конструкторе нового класса с параметрами

Tags: c++, классы, ссылки, параметры

Как грамотно реализовать конструктор класса типа:

```
class NewClass
{
public:
    NewClass(Class1 &Name1, Class2 &Name2 )
...
};
```

если количество различных классов Class1 и Class2 значительное?

Для небольшого количества классов (Class1 и Class2) можно перебрать вручную все возможные перегрузки конструктора, а что делать если таких классов будет много или вообще произвольное количество?

Comment: Может быть просто поместить эти классы в массив (или вектор) и передать конструктору?

Comment: Я не уверен, что понял суть))) попытаюсь конкретезировать вопрос. Данный код используется для реализации гидравлического расчета сети. И выдлядит следующим образом (например):
class Pipe
{
public:
    Pipe(Tank &pipeEnd1, Node &pipeEnd2 )
...
};
т.е. класс труба и два объекта на ее концах класса бак и класса соединение. Но возможных вариаций много, минимум 5-6 различных классов.

Comment: https://rsdn.org/forum/cpp/418970.1